# What is a good storytelling way to change a characters class?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, story, player-characters

So let's say I am playing a bard.

But now my bard is level 7 and I would like to change the class because I'm just not feeling it anymore. Now I want to play the same character. I still want the NPC's to recognize my character.  What are good ways to do this, so I don't just randomly become for example a sorcerer?

Did you ever change your class "mid-game"?
How did you do it?

What is a good storytelling way to change a characters class?

Comment: How are you defining 'good' here?

Comment: @NautArch Not just saying he fell on his head and has now the knowledge of a lv. 7 mage. Something with a real story / reason.

Comment: @Reitô Hello and welcome! Unfortunately, we don't really serve idea generation here, but if you get 20 reputation you can ask for ideas and discuss in [chat]. I can relate to your feelings though!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because overly broad and seeks idea generation.

Comment: Do you mean just changing classes, or adding new levels in another class?

Comment: The SE format doesn't handle idea generation very well.  An internet forum is usually a better place to do that. we have [a curated list here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)

Comment: @Davo changing class and keeping the lv as it was with the other class

Comment: Probably a duplicate of these questions: [How can a PC change their class in middle of an Adventure?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44584/how-can-a-pc-change-their-class-in-middle-of-an-adventure), [Is class retraining an option in D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80406/is-class-retraining-an-option-in-dd-5e)